# How can 2 JVMs talk with Per-User Authentication

Tags: java, windows, jvm, netty, named-pipes

Similar to [How to have 2 JVMs talk to one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942427/how-to-have-2-jvms-talk-to-one-another), but with the added requirement that there be per-user authentication between the 2 JVMs.  I have one Windows machine that multiple users will utilize, each using 2 java applications (essentially a client process and server process). The communication should be isolated, such that no user can see or access the data moving between another user's client/server.

I'm looking at named pipes and Netty as of now, but not sure of how each supports the above requirement, or which is more reliable / easier to set up.