# How does a native calling application get a return value from JNLP?

Tags: java, client, jnlp

I am launching a JNLP java application from a native client app (i.e. not a browser). When the JNLP finishes it's task, I need it to return a string to the calling app? How can I do this? Is it possible to return a value to a calling app - or do I need to have the calling app listen on a port and have the JNLP app write the value to that port through sockets?

Comment: Please, can you post an example of how are you doing the call?

Comment: @karelss - javaws <jnlp file> is called by Process::Start in C#

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question!

I write to stdout from the child process (the JNLP)

- The parent launches the child process

  ```
  Process::Start
  ```
- Read stdout from Parent

  ```
  string ret = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  ```
- ```
  Process::WaitForExit();
  ```

Anyone sees any problem in this?

Answer (score 1):

If the `all-permissions` element is specified, you could try to set an environment variable which you can read from your C# application.

Set environment variable in Java:

```
System.getenv().put("returnValue", "yourValue");
```

Read environment variable in C#:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("start ....");
....
string returnValue = p.EnvironmentVariables["returnValue"];
```

Comment: Don't think this will work - child is a separate process - it inherits a copy of the env variables of the parent - any changes in the variable values in the child will not be reflected in the parent - at least this is how it works on most operating systems - will test it on windows and see.

Answer (score 1):

I like your idea to use sockets and think this is could be an easy solution.

It is not possible to get return values from a WebStart-application. Just see the help message from

```
javaws --help
```

There is no return-code available. (Sorry)

Have you thougth on a temporary file instead of the sockets?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old but as fas as i know this is the exiting options to intercommunicate two process [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942427/how-to-have-2-jvms-talk-to-one-another).

I think the easiest way to solve your problem is use rmi, or jmx if you can, or just a simple socket