# Share Process / Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, process, processbuilder

I am facing a problem regarding Process and Threads. My Scenario is:

- My Java Application, call it 'Starter-App', starts another exe Application (Diagnosis.exe) with `ProcessBuilder` within a named `Thread`:

  ```
  Thread startGXThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
      @Override       
      public void run() {
          try {
              ...
              File gxExe = new File(pathToGX); // Path to Diagnosis.exe
              gxp = pb.start();
              gxp.waitFor();

          } catch (IOException e) {
              LOG.error("Can't start module");
              LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              LOG.debug("thread interrupted. Destroy process");
              LOG.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
              if (gxp != null) {
                  gxp.destroy();
                  LOG.debug("process exit value: " + gxp.exitValue());
              }
          }
      }
  }, "diag_thrd");
  ```
- Afterwards a jetty webserver (ServiceWebApp) is started with a webapp.
- start chromium and 'Starter-App' listen when its closed.
- Once chromium closes 'Starter-App' recognizes this and stops jetty and also terminate the startet application.Diagnosis.exe. This is done by:

  ```
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          stopAsync();
      }
  });

  public static void stopAsync() {
      Thread diag = getThread("diag_thrd");
      if (diag != null) {
          diag.interrupt();
      }
      if (gxp != null) {
          gxp.destroy();
          LOG.debug("process exit value: " + gxp.exitValue());
      }
  }
  ```

Question:
I need to be able to stop the startet Diagnosis.exe from within the webapp and start it again, while still be able to destroy/shutdown the Diagnosis.exe once chromium stops within 'Starter-App'.
I hope I could explain my problem and hope for suggestions.

Comment: So the Starter-App starts Diagnosis.exe, a jetty server and Chromium?

Comment: That is right. The 'Starter-App' starts Diagnosis.exe, Jetty (with a deployed webapp), and Chromium (with url to the webapp). Once Chromium closes (by user) 'Starter-App' recognizes this and shuts down jetty and Diagnosis.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Anands answer, I think you need some form of IPC between the Diagnosis.exe and your Starter-App, using websockets, or a number of other options, for some ideas: [How to have 2 JVMs talk to one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942427/how-to-have-2-jvms-talk-to-one-another).

The webapp would send a request for restarting Diagnosis.exe to the Starter-App and the Starter-App would stay in charge of managing the application trio at all time.

Comment: Liked this idea - The webapp would send a request for restarting Diagnosis.exe to the Starter-App and the Starter-App would stay in charge of managing the application trio at all time.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a solution but a but tricky to implement.

You can always use *nix api's like `ps kill #pid` as explained in the example here [Killing a process using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java)

But your webserver has to know which PID's to look for. The only option I see to implement such thing is using sockets or webservices. So you keep track of what is the current pid of Diagnosis.exe process, and use that Id before killing.

Comment: I am using windows. So it would probably not be `ps kill`. I could pass the pid as a system paramter to the webapp but once the web app is shut down the 'starter-app's reference is not valid anymore.

Comment: Yeah. Windows will have different option. Also I would not recommend sending PID as system parameter, but that should be sent as a heart-beat or some RMI/Webservice call. because There is a possibility of webserver restarting the process. So whosoever restarts the Diagnostic.exe notifies other of the new process Id to look for.