# How to achieve inter-instance synchronization in java?

Tags: java, spring, synchronization, thread-safety

Suppose I have a Java Spring application having a synchronized method (thread-safe). If my application is deployed on a single instance, then I can say that it's thread safe. However, to scale, we must deploy on multiple instances. How to achieve inter-instance synchronization?

Comment: There are many ways. This question is not specific enough. Bottom line, there needs to be some communication/coordination between the processes.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't seem to be about thread-safety. A single application can have multiple threads, and certain methods in an application can be thread-safe or -unsafe.

With that, if you have multiple instances of a given application that needs access to communicate, then its as @Michael in the comments said: it is a form of inter-process communication (IPC). There are two ways to achieve this: message passing and shared memory. Some examples of this can be found at this answer: [How to have 2 JVMs talk to one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942427/how-to-have-2-jvms-talk-to-one-another)

However, since you are using Java Spring, a web framework, you are likely already working with network based services. Why not have multiple instances of the same service share state through an external shared service? This sounds like a great use-case for Message Brokers like [Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/redis/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). As Reddis states as their homepage states:

> Chat, messaging, and queues
>
> Redis supports Pub/Sub with pattern matching and a variety of data
> structures such as  lists, sorted sets, and hashes. This allows Redis
> to support high performance chat  rooms, real-time comment streams,
> social media feeds and server intercommunication.  The Redis List data
> structure makes it easy to implement a lightweight queue. Lists  offer
> atomic operations as well as blocking capabilities, making them
> suitable for a  variety of applications that require a reliable
> message broker or a circular list.